# pandas get_indexer returns all -1 for single interval

Tags: python, pandas

I can't make sense of why this interval lookup does not give me what I'd expect as a 0 index match for all data points in the following example:

```
import pandas  

dfLbl  = pandas.DataFrame( { 'Started':[554235706.051] , 'Stopped':[554240454.867] , 'Label':['LblVal'] } )
dfData = pandas.DataFrame( {'Angle': [-89.460618, -90.053987, -89.735639, -179.248331, 90.405555, 0.541808, 1.257457, 0.16111] ,
                            'time_s':[554237043.713062, 554238249.989954, 554235853.912149, 554237638.876251, 554237007.218903, 554239665.777394, 554238786.764156, 554239549.519223] })

print( "dfData\n{}".format( dfData ))
print( "\ndfLbl\n{}".format( dfLbl ))

lbl_intervals = pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays( dfLbl['Started'] , dfLbl['Stopped'] , closed='neither' )
lbl_indexes   = lbl_intervals.get_indexer( dfData['time_s'] )

print( "\nlbl_intervals\n{}".format( lbl_intervals ))
print( "\nlbl_indexes\n{}".format( lbl_indexes ))

print( "\n{}".format( pandas.DataFrame( { 'a <= x':  dfLbl.loc[0,'Started'] <= dfData['time_s'] , 'x < b' : dfData['time_s'] < dfLbl.loc[0,'Stopped']} )  ))
print(  "\nIntervalWidth={}".format( dfLbl['Stopped'] - dfLbl['Started'] ))
```

Which gives the following console output

```
dfData
        Angle        time_s
0  -89.460618  5.542370e+08
1  -90.053987  5.542382e+08
2  -89.735639  5.542359e+08
3 -179.248331  5.542376e+08
4   90.405555  5.542370e+08
5    0.541808  5.542397e+08
6    1.257457  5.542388e+08
7    0.161110  5.542395e+08

dfLbl
    Label       Started       Stopped
0  LblVal  5.542357e+08  5.542405e+08

lbl_intervals
IntervalIndex([(554235706.051, 554240454.867)]
              closed='neither',
              dtype='interval[float64]')

lbl_indexes
[-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]

   a <= x   x < b
0    True    True
1    True    True
2    True    True
3    True    True
4    True    True
5    True    True
6    True    True
7    True    True

IntervalWidth=0    4748.816
dtype: float64
```

I'm completely baffled since when I manually do the inequality as you see in the `a <= x` and `x < b` columns it shows the `time_s` data is in bounds. I checked the width of the indexer is not some unreasonably small number. What else could be going wrong here? Is there something fallacious about using a single interval for this sort of operation? Is pandas coercing the value to some other type that's breaking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug in the version of pandas I was using. I reviewed the GitHub [What's New page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0232) and found a few bug fixes involving indexing. So I upgraded...

```
$ pip install --upgrade pandas
...
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Found existing installation: pandas 0.22.0
    Uninstalling pandas-0.22.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pandas-0.22.0
Successfully installed pandas-0.23.4
```

And reran the script and found the console output now gives what is expected...

```
dfData
        Angle        time_s
0  -89.460618  5.542370e+08
1  -90.053987  5.542382e+08
2  -89.735639  5.542359e+08
3 -179.248331  5.542376e+08
4   90.405555  5.542370e+08
5    0.541808  5.542397e+08
6    1.257457  5.542388e+08
7    0.161110  5.542395e+08

dfLbl
    Label       Started       Stopped
0  LblVal  5.542357e+08  5.542405e+08

lbl_intervals
IntervalIndex([(554235706.051, 554240454.867)]
              closed='neither',
              dtype='interval[float64]')

lbl_indexes
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] <--------- ALL ZEROS

   a <= x   x<b
0    True  True
1    True  True
2    True  True
3    True  True
4    True  True
5    True  True
6    True  True
7    True  True

IntervalWidth=0    4748.816
dtype: float64
```